# How to repeat a character in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to repeatedly print a character inside a table cell in HTML (NOT HTML5!)?

*(only using HTML OR using HTML and CSS ONLY)

** Need to print "."  through the full length of a cell. Don't know the exact width of the cell!

Comment: Type the character twice...? Do you have a more concrete use case?

Comment: this is not possible without hardcoding the characters multiple times

Comment: Use a background image. See @Rene Koch Answer!

Comment: I think you must use the java script to handle this.

Comment: Seems like some people are **really** good at down voting! I've asked this because I needed to know whether someone else in the community knows the answer which I have failed to find out after some research by my own! Is that _"down-votable"_ offense in stackoverflow?

Comment: +1 -- i need to do the same thing (the answer below is great)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after u elaborated your question I have the solution.
A div with a dotted bottom border and text with a white background on top.

example :

CSS:

```
.line{
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    position:relative;
    height:16px;
}

.line span{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    bottom:-2px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.line .price{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="line">
    <span class="title">name</span>
    <span class="price">123.23$</span>
</div>
<div class="line">
    <span class="title">name</span>
    <span class="price">123.23$</span>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bKuVe/

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally ran into this question and couldn't stop myself from posting my own answer.

I use this method for few years now and I love it for it's simplicity. The whole idea is to use `float: left|right` for elements with text while the `block` element surrounding it will produce a margin. We take advantage of this by adding `overflow: hidden` to the block element.
Another improvement here, is the usage of `::after` pseudo-class instead of the actual block element. That makes perfect sense since the dots should act more like the part of the stylesheet.

```css
.line {
    padding: 60px 0;
}
.title {
    float: left;
}
.price {
    float: right;
}
.line::after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    min-height: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
    <span class="title">name</span>
    <span class="price">123.23$</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like coding, you can try something like this:

```
var tag = [tag];
var h = tag[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
while(h===tag[0].getBoundingClientRect().height){
    tag[0].innerHTML+='-';
};
tag[0].innerHTML=tag[0].innerHTML.replace('-','');
```

Answer (score 0):

how about making a background image and repeat-x ?

```
 background:url(character.png) repeat-x;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using plain HTML (I mean not using any server generated HTML), write the character more than once. If you are using server generated HTML (like PHP, JSP, etc.), you can write the character more than once or use loop. This cannot be done in client side ***unless*** you're using JavaScript.