# CSS for text with line and image on right

Tags: html, css

I need to create HTML rows where there is a text (with variable width), a line (or an hr) and an image.

Text is with a variable length, and the image have a fixed width.
I need something like:

VARIABLETEXT----------------------------------IMAGE

and this rows may be always 100% width.

I tried with the same CSS, but without result.

How I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please write down what kind of CSS and HTML you wrote?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**

Comment: <div class="container><div class="text"></div><div class="linetext"></div><div class="lineimage"></div></div>

Comment: Edit your question with the code you provided on your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before by making the line go 100% of the width and floating the end elements.  Using `position` you can then place the line behind the other two.

Set the `background-color` of the two floated elements to the same color of parent background such that it doesn't show the line behind them, and will appear like the line is expanding/contracting

[image]

Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/0sqL5bc9/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this

Follow this thread you may find answer [How to repeat a character in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153944/how-to-repeat-a-character-in-html)

**Example**

```
<div class="line"> 
    <span ><label for="text">VARIABLETEXT</label></span>
    <span class="image">image</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line{
border-bottom:1px dotted black;
position:relative;
height:16px;
}

.line span{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    bottom:-2px;
    height:100%;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.line .image{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Link here for [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/cdj35hpu/)

Comment: This work very fine! Thanks! Sorry but I'm a newbie with css. I start a new course just yesterday. Thanks