# How Can I Create Dotted Lines to Display Data in Rows in ReactJS using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a short design like this in `Reactjs`

```
Monday......................08:00 AM - 21:00 PM
```

As you see above I have many dots, how can I create it shorter without entering many dots like that.
Enter dot [....] like this is not good for the website.

Any idea about this. Could you support me, please

Comment: This question has already been answered: [How to repeat a character in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153944/how-to-repeat-a-character-in-html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in `CSS` using dotted [borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border). In my example below I have utilized the Flex layout. Reposition the dots as necessary as I indicated in the CSS code comments.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="dotted-data-container">
        <div className="dotted-data-key">Monday</div>
        <div className="dotted-data-separator"></div>
        <div className="dotted-data-value">08:00 AM - 21:00 PM</div>
      </div>
      <div className="dotted-data-container">
        <div className="dotted-data-key">Saturday</div>
        <div className="dotted-data-separator"></div>
        <div className="dotted-data-value">08:00 AM - 21:00 PM</div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.dotted-data-container {
    display: flex;
}

.dotted-data-separator {
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted; /* style as necessary */
    position: relative;
    top: -2px; /* reposition as necessary */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'd just mention that *dotted* borders are inconsistent across the browsers. [Example](https://www.impressivewebs.com/comparison-css-border-style/) (article from 2011).

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

`[...new Array(numberOfDots)].map(()=> ".").join("")`